# How To Get Slider Value of Next Column In Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to get the slider value of the current row when the users changes any of the inputs for class="entryprice_class".

Commented out in the code is some of what I have tried.

I have been at this for hours. Still no luck.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">

        <!-- entry points table -->
        <section id="entry_points_section">
            <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                <table class="responsive" id="input_entries_table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" id="entry_price_column">Entry price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Percent</th>
                        <th scope="col">Order amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">Capital value</th>
                        <th scope="col">Breakeven</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="number" class="entryprice_class"
                                                                     id="entryprice_1" size="5" min="0" placeholder="0"
                                                                     value="0"></td>
                        <td style="min-width:2em"><input type="range" name="slider-fill_1" class="entry_percent"
                                                         id="entry_percent_1" value="50" placeholder="50%" min="0"
                                                         max="100"
                                                         data-highlight="true"/></td>
                        <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="order_amount"
                                                                     name="order_amount" size="5" min="0"
                                                                     placeholder="0" length="10px" disabled></td>
                        <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="capital_value"
                                                                     name="capital_value" size="5" min="0"
                                                                     placeholder="0" disabled></td>
                        <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="breakeven" name="breakeven"
                                                                     size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" disabled></td>
                        <td width="28px" style="display:none">
                            <button data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">
                                &nbsp;</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="number" class="entryprice_class"
                                                                     name="entryprice" id="entryprice_2" size="5"
                                                                     min="0" placeholder="0" value="0"></td>
                        <td style="min-width:2em"><input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="entry_percent_2" value="50"
                                                         placeholder="50%" min="0" max="100"
                                                         data-highlight="true"/></td>
                        <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="order_amount"
                                                                     name="order_amount" size="5" min="0"
                                                                     placeholder="0" length="10px" disabled></td>
                        <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="capital_value"
                                                                     name="capital_value" size="5" min="0"
                                                                     placeholder="0" disabled></td>
                        <td width="17%" style="min-width:3em"><input type="text" class="breakeven" name="breakeven"
                                                                     size="5" min="0" placeholder="0" disabled></td>
                        <td width="28px"><a href="#" class="remove_field">
                            <button data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">
                                &nbsp;</button>
                        </a></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div>
                        <button id='add_new_entry_button' data-icon="plus" data-inline="false">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


    </div></div>


    <!-- /page -->

    <script>

        var entryprice = $('.entryprice_class');
        var entryprice_totals = $('#entryprice_totals_1');


        entryprice.live('change', function () {

            entry_price = $(':focus').val();

            alert(entry_price);

            var current_percent = $(this).next('td').next("input").val();

            alert(slider_value);


            //var current_percent = $(this).closest('tr').attr('val'); // table row ID
            //var current_percent = $(this).closest('tr').where// table row ID
            //  $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').show();



            //alert($row.val(), row.val());

            //var current_percent =  $(this).siblings('.entry_percent').val();

            //var current_percent =  $(this).next('input').val();

            // var current_percent = $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('#entry_percent_1');

            //var current_percent = $('.entry_percent').val();
            //var current_percent = $(this).closest("td").next().find("input").slider("option", "value");

            //var current_percent = $(this).next('td').next("input").val();

            //var current_percent = $(this).next('.entry_percent').val();
            //var current_percent = $(this).next("input[name='slider-fill']").val();

            // var current_percent = $(this).closest('input .entry_percent').val();

            //var current_percent = $(this).closest("div.options").find("input[name='slider-fill_1']").val();

            //var current_percent = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name='slider-fill_1']").val();


            //var current_percent = $(this).parent().next().children('.entry_percent').val( this.value );

            //var current_percent = $(this).sibling().val();


            // var current_percent = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='slider-fill']").val();

            // current_percent = $(':focus').next('td').find("input[name='slider-fill']").val();


            alert(current_percent);



        });




    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    var entryprice_totals = $('#entryprice_totals_1');


    $('.entryprice_class').on('change', function () {

        entry_price = $(':focus').val();

        alert(entry_price);

        // this one works with jQuery Mobile 1.2.0
        var current_percent = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:nth-child(2) input' ).val();

        // var current_percent = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="range"]' ).val();

        alert(current_percent);

    });
```

I used the `closest` method to find the nearest table row, and after that the `find` method was used to find  input type range value. You came very close of finding the right solution. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/rsa1qb46/1/)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/rsa1qb46/1/)

Comment: Thanks so much.  But something strange is going on.  When I add the reference to jquerymobile (    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
), I get an 'undefined' for the variable value.  Without that js it works?

Comment: @Sage  updated fiddle to make it work with jQuery Mobile version 1.2.0. The previous one worked jQuery Mobile version 1.4.2

Comment: @Sage Cheers. Don't worry it takes a while to get to know jQuery well -  I've been there too. Soon you'll be giving out answers in this forum :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use that:

```
var current_percent = $(this).parent().next("td").find("input[id^='entry_percent']").val();
```

This works.

Comment: And jsfiddle link is here : [http://jsfiddle.net/cqpuj0jy/](http://jsfiddle.net/cqpuj0jy/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the class `entry_percent` to all sliders in every row, like this:

```
<input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="entry_percent_2" class="entry_percent" value="50" placeholder="50%" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true">
```

then use this JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".entryprice_class").on("change", function () {
        var val = $(this).closest("tr").find(".entry_percent").val();
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

For more information see these documentation pages:

- https://api.jquery.com/closest/
- https://api.jquery.com/find/